Filtered reverse of a one to many relation in Django
I have a model called Item and another called ItemSynonym with a one to many relation like so:
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

from project.utils.models import UUIDModel 

class Item(UUIDModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class ItemSynonym(UUIDModel):
    marker = models.ForeignKey(
        Marker,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="synonyms",
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

I would now like to add a new field to the ItemSynonym model called language code so that it becomes:
class ItemSynonym(UUIDModel):
    marker = models.ForeignKey(
        Marker,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="synonyms",
    )
    language_code = models.CharField(
        db_index=True,
        max_length=8,
        verbose_name="Language",
        choices=settings.LANGUAGES,
        default=settings.LANGUAGE_CODE,
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

However I would like to filter I am wondering if it is possible somehow to filter the synonyms by only modifying the models, so that I don't have to hunt through the entire code base and filter synonyms individually so something like:
class Item(UUIDModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    synonyms = models.FilteredRelation(
        "all_synonyms",
        condition=models.Q(language_code=get_language()),
    )

class ItemSynonym(UUIDModel):
    marker = models.ForeignKey(
        Marker,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="all_synonyms",
    )
    language_code = models.CharField(
        db_index=True,
        max_length=8,
        verbose_name="Language",
        choices=settings.LANGUAGES,
        default=settings.LANGUAGE_CODE,
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

Though obviously the above doesn't work, otherwise I wouldn't be here. I've also tried adding an annotation for the FilteredRelation inside a custom manager for Item`, but for whatever reason the annotation isn't even accessible as a property.
I'm fairly new to Django, but I'm sure this isn't an uncommon problem so I would also appreciate any info on what the idiomatic way to filter such relations is.

Yes, you can filter when prefetching with a Prefetch [Django-doc] object:
from django.db.models import Prefetch

items = Item.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('all_synonyms', ItemSynonym.objects.filter(language_code='tr'))
)
for example if we retrieve these and enumerate over these:
for item in items:
    for synonym in item.all_synonyms.all():
        print(synonym)  # only Turkish ones
We thus will only get the Turkish ones.

So you are saying this is not possible on the model level? I would have to modify all the viewsets, commands, etc.. that try to access synonyms, correct?

@kaan_atakan: I would hope it is not possible on the model level, since models should be request unaware, and thus not consider the language, cookies, etc. of that request.
